# Redis fetch all value of list without iteration and without popping

Tags: redis

I have simple redis list key => "supplier_id"

Now all I want it retrieve all value of list without actually iterating over or popping the value from list

Example to retrieve all the value from a list Now I have iterate over redis length

```
element = []
0.upto(redis.llen("supplier_id")-1) do |index| 
  element << redis.lindex("supplier_id",index)
 end
```

can this be done **without the iteration** perhap with better redis modelling . can anyone suggest

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do with the redis list? maybe you should use a different key type.

Comment: @eyossi The idea is to create a select tag with options value been  the supplier_id presented databases since retrieve of record in relational databases was expensive that y we thought of dumping all the supplier_id in redis when the are created and delete them when they are destroyed from database

Comment: There is official Redis documentation on Lists which explains this in more detail. More at https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-lists

Answer (score 226, accepted):

To retrieve all the items of a list with Redis, you do not need to iterate and fetch each individual items. It would be really inefficient.

You just have to use the [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) command to retrieve all the items in one shot.

```
elements = redis.lrange( "supplier_id", 0, -1 )
```

will return all the items of the list without altering the list itself.

Comment: If by memory efficient you mean incrementally iterating on the items, it can be implemented using llen and looping on lrange calls, but it will increase the number of roundtrips, and you will loose consistency.

Comment: Everytime i try this i get the error "Invalid argument(s)"

Comment: @DidierSpezia This returns in reverse order of my addition into redis. Is there a way to get output in order of insertion?

Comment: If you insert with RPUSH instead of LPUSH, it will be in the same order.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit unclear on your question but if the supplier_id is numeric, why not use a `ZSET`?

Add your values like so:

```
ZADD suppliers 1 "data for supplier 1"  
ZADD suppliers 2 "data for supplier 2"  
ZADD suppliers 3 "data for supplier 3"
```

You could then remove everything up to (but not including supplier three) like so:

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE suppliers -inf 2
```

or

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE suppliers -inf (3
```

That also gives you very fast access (by supplier id) if you just want to read from it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: can you provide the documentation for that sure it can certainly help

Comment: Z* is for sorted sets and the sort order "score" is being hacked to represent the supplier id. If the data being used is not exclusively unique for each supplier it won't work though. For example if the data being stored is "true" or "false", then `ZADD suppliers 1 true` `ZADD suppliers 2 false` will correctly result in stored data of `[1 => true, 2 => false]`. But then running `ZADD suppliers 3 true` will result in `[3 => true, 2 => false]` which may not be the original intent